# Emacs ESS version of Clear Console

Tags: emacs, r, ess

Is there an ESS version of the Clear Console command that can be found in the RGui(Ctrl-L)?

I want to have a blank * R * buffer.

Comment: +1 this one was bugging me for quite a while... and, BTW `C-l` keybinding is not available only in RGui, but in R interactive session on *NIX systems also. It's kind-of universal for all *NIX shells. =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShellMode), this Elisp function works well for me:

```
(defun clear-shell ()
   (interactive)
   (let ((old-max comint-buffer-maximum-size))
     (setq comint-buffer-maximum-size 0)
     (comint-truncate-buffer)
     (setq comint-buffer-maximum-size old-max)))
```

Put this in your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` and execute with `M-x clear-shell`, or bind it to a key in your `init.el` with something like:

`(global-set-key  (kbd "\C-x c") 'clear-shell)`

Comment: this is really neat. Is there a way I can _send_ this when I am in another window? If I try to do either `clear-shell' or `C-x c` when I am not in the window with the active shell I get an error; `processp, nil`. I am new to emacs so please bear with me if I have overlooked something basic.

Answer (score 11):

Execute `M-x comint-clear-buffer` which is bound to `C-c M-o`

Answer (score 8):

The easy way would be to mark the whole buffer (`C-x h`), delete it, and then hit `RET` to have the prompt come back.